# Extending "Share" options list on web google maps "share" dialog

Tags: google-maps

I'm building a chrome extension, and one functionality I'd like to add is to allow users sending selected lat/long to a 3rd party service. There is a standard UI for that ( click on a place -> details sidebar opens -> click share button -> share dialog appears ), but it only has 2 fixed services - facebook and twitter.

[image]

Is there a documented way of adding more items to that dialog? ( desktop web experience )

Comment: I don't know if there's an official way of doing it, however, you can poll to check if there's an input field with `https://goo.gl...` and then find the location yourself by following the DOM. It should be easy to add a new item there afterward. Though I'm pretty sure Google wouldn't allow such an extension on their store.

Comment: that was my last resort, if nothing better I'll do that way. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cost-of-driving-in-google/glajpeclpoeodmfofkelgedjphkdgmie is doing exactly that so looks like you cant get it onto store

Comment: typo - s/cant/can